# Actual random numbers in JS

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

I'm probably missing something here, and I'd like to know what, but it seems to me that generating unique numbers in JS is about the easiest thing in the world. Honestly I expect to get punked hard on this, but doesn't this generate an irrefutably unique number (of reasonable length)?

```
function getRandom() {

      let     date = new Date(),
              time = date.getTime();

      

      console.log(time * Math.random());
}
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you expect?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but it seems that generating unique numbers with computers is important to some people. The question is: do you think it works?

Comment: See [`Crypto.getRandomValues()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues)

Comment: OH -so it's a solved problem and I should consider myself punked? :-)

Comment: Yea don't feel bad, it's important that people see questions like this.

Comment: There is no such thing as actual random number or truly random number in this world. In a completely deterministic system, you cannot generate a random number. The best you can do is to use pseudorandom number generator.

Comment: Hey, @ c0m1t. For real, it looks like you know a lot more about coding than I do (which is kind of why I asked the question) but if you have the time and the inclination, can you please explain how the two line function could ever repeat a return?

Comment: @c0m1t that is not necessarily true. There are random number systems based on physically random phenomena, like (no joke) a wall of "Lava Lamps" with a video camera pointed at them.

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the question, and it really depends how you define words. But **probably there really are no deterministic systems**. There is no such thing as physical random phenomena. If we havent found out how some certain sytems work or cannot predict their future because of some limitation, it does not mean they are random. Chaotic systems and  quantum indeterminacy might be some good examples. If there is an event that is unpredictable today, it may be predictable tomorrow. This is what is known as pseudo randomness. As far as we all know, everything is deterministic.

Comment: You seem to be mixing two adjectives: _random_ and _unique_. However, they are different: Random does not exist (it is only a perception). Unique is just the state of a comparison to some other value. In regard to numbers: all JavaScript numbers are [double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic), so there can only be a limited set — and the only way to guarantee uniqueness is to store every unique number that you generate, comparing each newly-generated number to every prior one, and throw it away if you find a duplicate.

Comment: @jsejcksn You said “*the only way to guarantee uniqueness is to store every unique number that you generate, comparing each newly-generated number to every prior one, and throw it away if you find a duplicate*” — This is not correct. PRNGs give us two counterexamples, Linear Congruential Generators and Linear Feedback Shift Register Generators, which when properly parameterized can both produce full cycles of values without repeats and without storing all previously generated values.

Comment: @jsejcksn You also boldly state "*Random does not exist (it is only a perception)*" as if that were a fact rather than an opinion. My opinion differs from yours. The essence of randomness is that you can't predict outcomes with certainty. If you're claiming that you could predict with certainty in all circumstances, you're mistaken. You would need to be able to determine the state and the state transformation function for all systems in the universe, and mathematical systems theory has proven that there are systems where the state is not observable, regardless of how long you measure them.

Comment: @jsejcksn See the Wikipedia article for more info on [observability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observability).

Comment: @pjs I think you might have misinterpreted the intention of my comment — it wasn’t to establish any formal definitions — rather just to help the OP consider the actual criteria of the question being asked (they said they weren’t sure about expected results and the question itself isn’t very clear). I don’t think comments are the right place to debate things like semantics, but if that’s something you’d like to do, you’re welcome to start a new chat with me.

Comment: @donkeyotey your continued pointers to `deafinoneeye [.] com` look like attempts at SEO as the site appears unrelated to the question.  any comments?

Comment: Hi, @Sam Mason. I'm just a guy who used to be a front end developer, who is making an Android game and NOT Otto's evil empire. I am however giving away free ebooks for five days - starting in two days' time. So, yes, I'm clearly trying to give away some books, but my intentions are not motivated by filthy lucre :-). The book is a (proven) set of psychodynamic techniques which completely removes every speck of fear from any human mind (seriously, even though I know it sounds like BS/insane). It is also a demystification of spirituality. You can read the opening section on my site :-)

Answer (score 4):

`Math.random()` is a random number source whose precise behavior is not explicitly specified. It is, in almost all known runtimes, *not* a cryptographically-secure random number source. In particular, it may generate duplicate numbers at an indeterminate frequency.

Multiplying by the current time does not really increase randomness, because a theoretical attacker who understands your scheme would be able to guess at the time interval a particular random value was generated.

The general rule is that it is an extremely bad idea to try and concoct your own security scheme. Use something available that's been developed by a person who knows what they're doing. I've been in the software development business for over 40 years and I would never second-guess the state-of-the-art in things like CSRG packages.

Comment: Thanks, Pointy, so what you're saying (basically) is that the numbers generated by Math.random() are easily predicted?

Comment: @donkeyotey well there's "easy" and there's "easy".  Cryptographically-secure random numbers are generated by rigorously-tested algorithms, and (almost certainly) `Math.random()` is not one of those. If you care about security of your random numbers, you might as well care a lot.

Comment: Man! I did sculpture in college :-). I was a front end developer for about ten years. I don't know shit about coding: the first time I saw if !i-- to exit a loop I thought I was looking into the mind of God :-). But for real, can anyone either explain (or link to an explanation) of how this thing could ever repeat?

Comment: @donkeyotey well the key point is that if you want something *secure* you have to pick something that is explicitly *intended* to be secure. I know it seems a little extreme, but again, if what you're trying to protect is valuable to *you*, it might be even more valuable to somebody else.

Comment: Hey, Pointy. Like I said - I just want someone to tell me why what seems like 2 lines which are (in my mind) guaranteed to return a unique number every time they run from now until infinity runs out don't obviously do that. I'm more interested in JS than security, to be honest - I don't have much to protect :-).

Comment: Or, what about this?

Comment: function getRandom() {

          let     date = new Date(),
                  time = date.getTime(),
                  multiplier = Math.random();



          console.log(time * Math.random() * multiplier);
}

Comment: Obviously, you could go to hundreds of Math.random()s and multiply all of them, but would it actually reduce the likeleyhood of repetition by a significant factor?

Comment: @donkeyotey `Math.random()` produces values uniformly in the range [0,1), and uniform distributions have maximum entropy (which means they're the hardest to correctly identify in a probabilistic sense). Multiplying hundreds of them converges rapidly towards zero, so in fact you take scale factor of time with maximum entropy to a one with extremely low entropy. In other words it makes things worse, not better.

Comment: One last comment on this (from me). I just figured out one place to get instant, infinite randomness - white noise. It would be clumsy to go through a tv, but surely computers can detect the same phenomenon, right? If they can then numbers generated from it could never possibly repeat (at least inside System One). Right?